# Mat-pseudo-checkbox icon off-center and smaller than usual

Tags: html, css, checkbox, angular-material

While implementing a list of checkboxes, it came to my attention that the mark when the checkbox is checked isn't styled the way it is supposed to be. When I compare it to the documentation, I notice it is a lot smaller and way off-center. I'm starting to wonder if this has something to do with my other css, or if I'm missing something.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="general-wrapper">
  <h3>Users ({{participants.length}})</h3>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="filterbar">
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Columns</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControl]="columns" multiple>
          <mat-select-trigger>
            {{columns.value ? columns.value[0] : ''}}
            <span *ngIf="columns.value?.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
              (+{{columns.value.length - 1}} {{columns.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
            </span>
          </mat-select-trigger>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let column of selectedColumns" [value]="column">{{column}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
... rest of page
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  /*change color of label*/
  color: #f59225 !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-underline {
  /*change color of underline*/
  background-color: #f59225 !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
  /*change color of underline when focused*/
  background-color: #f59225 !important;
  ;
}

::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
  background: #f59225;
}

.download-btn {
  background-color: #f59225;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}

.additional-selection {
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;

}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.filterbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}

mat-table {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%
}

.mat-row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.spinner-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.general-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
}

mat-cell:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

mat-cell {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.status ::ng-deep .mat-progress-spinner circle,
.mat-spinner circle {
  stroke: #f59225 !important;
}
```

this is what my checkboxes currently look like:
[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: I provided a CSS fix to this issue, but just as a general comment, you should try to avoid using `ng-deep` operators. They are [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), and you're effectively making global CSS without putting your CSS into a global CSS file, so maintaining it becomes messier.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a css issue with the library itself. I've noticed the same thing in my own instance of the library. You can override the mat styles with your own to fix it.

With the following css, I think the end result looks much better.

```css
.mat-option .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked::after {
  top: 3px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 5px;
  border-left: 3px solid currentColor;
}
```

[image: Updated css screenshot]